# Sheet metal on THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working with with `THREE.JS` and I need to create a sheet metal, that looks like this one: [image]

I started in this way:

- I create a Shape
- I put holes in the Shape object
- I extrude the Shape

So now I have a plane object with holes. My question is: Is there a way to create the deformations near holes?

Comment: You could create the deformations with a bump or displacement or normal map on the material. You could possibly do the holes with an alpha map, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to THREE.JS and I didn't know anything about maps. I checked the documentation and seems I need a texture image but I'm creating the object on demand and this object may have different size and different number of holes with different alignments. Can maps solve the problem?

Comment: You could just put 1 hole / bump in a map and repeat it. I would suggest doing a few easy tutorials to get to know three.js before attempting an ambitious project. This would give you a better foundation to make decisions on the best way to achieve the results you want.